# Написание класса Predicate на C++

Tags: c++, predicate

Пытался написать аналог класса `Predicate` в `Java` на `C++`. В итоге вышло какое-то убожество:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Predicate {

private:

    Predicate<T> *other;

public:

    virtual bool test(T &t) = 0;

    Predicate<T> AND(Predicate<T> other);

    Predicate<T> OR(Predicate<T> other);

    Predicate<T> negate();
};

template<typename T>
Predicate<T> Predicate<T>::AND(Predicate<T> other) {
    Predicate<T> *t = this;
    class TmpPredicate : Predicate {

        TmpPredicate() {
            this->other = other;
        }

        bool test(T &t) {
            return t->test(t) && other.test(t);
        }
    };
    return TmpPredicate();
}
```

Остальные функции пока не реализовал.

В общем, это всё очень убого, но я понятия не имею, как это сделать нормально. Можете подсказать?

По задумке этот класс должен функционировать, как `Predicate` в `Java`. В идеальном варианте для работы с ним не нужно выделять динамическую память, работа с динамической памятью должна быть реализована в `Predicate` в его внутренней реализации.

Пример:

```cpp
int main() {
    Predicate<char> p([](char c) { return c == 'A'; });
    Predicate<char> p2([](char c) { return c == 'B'; });
    cout << p('b') << '\n'; // 0
    cout << p.NOT()('a') << '\n'; // 1
    cout << p.AND(p2)('A') << '\n'; // 0
    cout << p.OR(p2)('B') << '\n'; // 1
    cout << p.OR(p2).OR(p)('A') << '\n'; // 1
    cout << p.OR(p2).OR(p).OR(p2)('a') << '\n'; // 0
}
```

Comment: Нормально это видимо не пытаться бездумно копировать дженерики из джавы. А если и пытаться, то какой-то конкретный функционал с конкретным применением. ¿Вот зачем вам понадобился `Predicate`?

Comment: @user7860670 для реализации SQL-запросов.

Comment: Приводите конкретный пример, лучше сразу со ссылкой на онлайн компилятор. А то так совершенно непонятно. Ведь существующие средства выполнения запросов вполне обходятся без джава предикатов.

Comment: Вы хотите строить логическое выражения (для формирования строки SQL запроса), или наоборот выполнять проверки в фильтре (в реализации своего аналога SQL)?

Comment: @Chorkov я хочу выполнить проверки в фильтре.

Comment: @user7860670 если честно, с ходу не могу придумать, как грамотно реализовать средства выполнения запросов без предикатов.

Comment: @user7860670 хотите сказать, что на C++ невозможно написать аналог класса `Predicate`?

Comment: ¿Почему невозможно? Возможно. Рантаймы для джавы пишут на С++. Только не целесообразно. А у вас тут типичная проблема XY: пытаетесь делать джава дженерик, а на самом деле хотели делать проверки в фильтре. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view

Comment: @user7860670 а как мне использовать `filter` для обработки SQL-запроса? Например, `... WHERE (id = 2 AND name = 'Mark') OR salary = 100`? Мне же надо какой-то составной фильтр составить тут.

Comment: ¿А для чего тут понадобится фильтр? Все же уже будет отфильтровано на сервере.

Comment: @user7860670 я свой недоSQL реализую.

Comment: Тогда стоит почитать книжку Компиляторы: принципы, технологии и инструменты.

Comment: @user7860670 да мне просто нужно сделать маленькое задание. На яве это делается в пару десятков строчек. Неужели на C++ это сделать так сложно?

Comment: На "маленькое задание" подобное ну никак не тянет.. *"На яве это делается в пару десятков строчек."* - это очень сильное заявление, даже с учетом доступности большего количества средств из коробки и отсутствия заморочек с памятью и производительностью... Или же тут очередной слой проблемы XY, и задание на самом деле очень далеко от написания своего недоSQL.

Comment: Используйте `std::function<bool(T)>` вместо `Predicate<T>` (это по сути он и есть.) Получите потерю производительности, но для теста - подойдет.

Comment: @Chorkov но ведь такой способ не сработает в случае, когда мне нужно обработать запрос вида `... WHERE (id = 2 AND name = 'Mark') OR salary = 100`.

Comment: @user7860670 ну говорю же, это недоSQL. Тем более, что в яве есть класс `Predicate`. Я к тому, что на яве всё это реализовать очень просто.

Comment: Если вопрос о реализации парсера строкового выражения,  - то промежуточный результат работы парсера (для подвыражения)  имеет переменный тип. Используйте `std::variant< std::function<bool(T)> , std::function<int(T)>, std::function<std::string(T)> >` с нужным списком типов.

Comment: @Chorkov что-то я не понял, если честно, зачем мне именно такой набор параметров и как его использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кто там говорил, что писать свой `Predicate` на `C++` не целесообразно?
По мне так получилось очень целесообразно.

```cpp
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class Predicate {

    using Tester = bool(*)(const T&);

    enum Action {
        Test,
        And,
        Or,
        Not
    };

    class Data {

    public:

        Action action;
        Predicate *first{}, *second{};
        Tester tester{};

        explicit Data(const Action &action) : action(action) {

        }

        ~Data() {
            delete first;
            delete second;
        }
    };

    shared_ptr<Data> data;

    explicit Predicate(const Action &action) {
        data = make_shared<Data>(action);
    }

    Predicate(const Predicate &p) : data(p.data) {

    }

    Predicate(const Predicate &p1, const Predicate &p2, const Action &action) : Predicate(action) {
        data->first = new Predicate(p1);
        data->second = new Predicate(p2);
    }

public:

    explicit Predicate(const Tester &tester) : Predicate(Test) {
        data->tester = tester;
    }

    bool test(const T &t) const {
        switch (data->action) {
            case Test:
                return data->tester(t);
            case And:
                return (*data->first).test(t) && (*data->second).test(t);
            case Or:
                return (*data->first).test(t) || (*data->second).test(t);
            case Not:
                return !(*data->first).test(t);
        }
    }

    bool operator()(const T &t) const {
        return test(t);
    }

    Predicate AND(const Predicate &other) const {
        return Predicate(*this, other, And);
    }

    Predicate OR(const Predicate &other) const {
        return Predicate(*this, other, Or);
    }

    Predicate NOT() const {
        Predicate notThis(Not);
        notThis.data->first = new Predicate(*this);
        return notThis;
    }
};
```